# css best practice questions

Tags: css, architecture

I have been debating using css with div's and laying out elements, and really am looking to see if the practice i've been using would be considered the best practice, or if there is something different that i'm over looking that would be better.

Lets say we were placing two images on the same line, on on the left one on the right then an text in the ad below it.  I might do something like:

```
#container{
 width:800px;
 height:300px;
}
.fleft{
  float:left;
}
#left_img_container{
  float:left;
  width:150px;
}
#right_img_container{
  float:right;
  width:150px;
  text-align:right;
}
#textArea{
  margin-top:5px;
  width:100%;
}

<div id='container'>
   <div class='fleft'>
       <div id='left_img_container'>FOO IMAGE 1</div>
       <div id='right_img_container'>FOO IMAGE 2</div>
   </div>
   <div class='fleft' id='textArea'>this is my text</div>
</div>
```

Simple example but illistrates the float kind of layout style.  Is this the better practice? or would using clear be better?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just noticing that your container is 800px, but your images only 150px each. So if you use `float:right`, the images would be separated by 500px. If you want them next to eachother use `float:left` on both images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fleft` as a class name is not good practice.

What if your client/boss says, *"alright, we want that div on the right?"*

You have 2 options... change the `fleft` class to be `float: right`, or make a new class and change it in the HTML. CSS classes should be titled by their meaning or description without using descriptive words which include position/colour/size etc.

The only exception I've found to the rule are images in an article. Since they generally float to the left and right, I do use class names `image-left` and `image-right`.

#### Examples

(from a bad name to a better name)

`top` => `header`

`left-side-bar` => `menu`

`bottom-menu` => `footer`

Of course, these are only examples. It's also good practice, because when HTML5 comes along, you'll actually define `<header>`, `<footer>`, etc

Comment: "What if your client/boss says, "alright, we want that image on the right?"  

Usually images like that can be given a descriptive class or id instead of a position in the name.

Comment: @Rob Not if they are inserted via a CMS. If I do have to give one an id, I'll opt for something that doesn't tie to the image. For example, if you had `<img src="big_dog.jpg" id="big-dog" />` and then your boss says "make it a small cat", you'll have more maintenance than you'll want.

Comment: Actually I meant something along the lines of id="splash-image" or "article-img" or some such.

Comment: @Rob it all depends on context.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably clean up your HTML code a bit, and use less classes in your CSS, like so:

```
<div id="container">
   <img id="foo1" src="foo1" />
   <img id="foo2" src="foo2" />
   <p>This is my text</p>
</div>

#container {
   width:800px;
   height:300px;
}

#foo1 {
   float:left;
}

#foo2 {
   float:right;
}

#container p {
   margin-top:5px;
   clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the implementation... But I do agree with Alex... You need to follow a more appropriate naming standard.... which would serve you better for the future...